# How to connect android studio emulator to a real WiFI and/or get access to an emulated device via ip

Tags: android, android-emulator, ip, wifi

***THE PROBLEM***

**1.** I'm running on Windows

**2.** I created an ADV Manager on android studio to test my application

**3.** I have an application that uses the discovery of Networks and sent packets to the existing devices to (discover) the installed app. I use c# and I discover the existing networks by NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

**4.** THE PROBLEM -> The android emulator doesn't appear on windows as a device to be discovered.
I want the emulator to be like a real device to be disovered, connected to a real WiFi, but I can only connect on "AndroidWifi" available by the ADV Manager.
I cannot even ping on windows, I've gone on the emulator to the wifi connection and got the ip by clicking on >Configuration>Wifi>IP Address, so I got the ip address 10.0.2.16, and I put on windows command line ping 10.0.2.16, but this ip is not discoverable

***WHAT IS NEEDED:***

**5.** I'd like to connect to a Real Wifi, e.g. in my house I have the WiFi called Leonios, but android emulator doesn't discover other wifis, **OR**

**6.** I'd like to discover the Device via ip somehow.

Comment: If it is not a Real Wifi, but a port forward, i.e. Host PC's port A is forwarded to emulator's port b, will that help?